# How to show numeric data as text

Tags: flutter, dart

I store user status information in the database but in numbers. I want to show it in listview builder but display it as text instead of numbers.The

number 0 shows an unauthorized message.

Number 1 shows allowed messages.

Number 2 shows the initial message.

How do I start building to get that result? I just started writing flutter.

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
 
  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  List<problemModel> originalList = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
   Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    originalList = problemlist;
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAllProblem();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
        title: const Text('show information'),
     ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
             )
             Expanded(
               child: StreamBuilder(
                 stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                           return Card(
                             margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                             child: ListTile(
                               leading: CircleAvatar(
                                 backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  'http://192.168.1.5/skc/Problem_image/${problem.image}',
                                ),
                              ), 
                              subtitle: Text(
                                problem.status,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
                   }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question isn't too clear. Maybe add a printscreen of the issue for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Raky's answer seem logical and should work properly, have you try cast your problem.status to Int before sending it to the `getStatusText()` method?

Here is the casting example:

```
subtitle: Text(
    getStatusText(int.parse(problem.status)),
    style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 17,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Yes, Raky's answer seems reasonable and should work properly, I tried what you suggested. and got an error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.

Comment: Oh, my bad I've some confusion here. Instead of using `problem.status.toString()` try `int.parse(problem.status.toString())`

Comment: Oh my god I fixed it as you suggested. int.parse(issue.status.toString())
 and got an error Argument type 'int' cannot be assigned to a parameter of type 'String'.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick. If it works for you, Remember to Accept the Answer and UpVote

```
class _view_problemState extends State<view_problem> {
 
  List<problemModel> problemlist = [];
  List<problemModel> originalList = [];
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
   Future getAllProblem() async {
    problemlist = await problemcontrollers().getProblem();
    originalList = problemlist;
    _streamController.sink.add(problemlist);
  }
  
  String getStatusText(int statusCode) {
    switch (statusCode) {
      case 0:
        return "Unauthorized";
      case 1:
        return "Authorized";
      case 2:
        return "Initial";
      default:
        return "UnRecognised"; 
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    getAllProblem();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 12, 134),
        title: const Text('show information'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: problemlist.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                        return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                'http://192.168.1.5/skc/Problem_image/${problem.image}',
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              getStatusText(problem.status),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said and got error. Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int')

Comment: @gamedevdover  what is the Data Type of user `status`? If it is `str` then change `String getStatusText(int statusCode)` to `String getStatusText(String statusCode)` and all numbers under case as strings. For Ex change `case 0:` to `case '0':`. That should resolve the error you are geting